# How to model an association class in a UML class diagram where only one of the class has access to it?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

Given this scenario: "Clinicians can record their own notes for each patient, viewable only by them." I would model it like this:

Clinician ----> Patient

and  "Notes" as an association class between clinician and patient. However, does this mean that the "Notes" class is viewable by both clinicians and patients? If so, how do I indicate that Notes can only be viewed by clinician?

Comment: what kind of uml arrow does your ascii represent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better don't. (Not saying it cannot be tweaked somehow into there, but I think it is not a good idea).

Class diagrams show properties of the actual classes, like access modifiers "private", "public" and "protected", not restrictions on the use cases for the users of your system. A view restriction of clinicians on notes is something which needs to be encoded into the application by certain features, non-features or access rights, and maybe by utilizing database access rights as well. This is a very different level of abstraction than the level a class diagram typically shows. (And don't intermix a class `Clinician` with the real person which sits in front of a workstation and uses the system.)

A sensible place where you can put such restrictions in UML is a use case diagram, inside the textual description of a use case "View Notes" or "Manage Notes", for example.

Comment: "*Don't intermix a class Clinician with the real person which sits in front of a workstation and uses the system*". This is going to leave me chuckling for many hours. The whole point of OO was that it was supposed to model "real world objects" as objects in code. That `Clinician` class exactly should be the only object able to access `Notes` as that mirrors the real world. Priceless. :-D

Comment: @DavidArno: so what? Do you agree, disagree, or have a better answer?

Comment: None of the above. It simply reinforces my view that UML is a total joke and it's a travesty that people are still being taught it.

Comment: @DavidArno: I think you are missing the point, since the OPs problem is not really an UML problem. In a typical real-world system,  Clinician, Patient, and Note will probably domain classes, maybe persisted in some DB. I doubt it will be a good idea to map the view restriction of clinicians to notes (from the described use case) directly to access restrictions on the class level. My gut tells me, these things are happening on a very different level of abstraction. Thus I think one should not try to abuse an UML class diagram for things which belong into a use case description.

Comment: I think you can do it in uml but you need a extra box showing that Notes is internal to Clinician

Comment: UML may be a joke if one were to attempt to follow all the rules which are required to create an executable model. However, nothing I have seen does a better job of helping to quickly identify issues, requirements and perform design of systems than using a UML-Tool. Although, I only use the features of UML that I like; admittedly I use many features/symbols of the tools in non-standard ways which IMO ends up making more sense.